# a |= (1 << 31) results in unexepected value

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, integer-promotion, bitwise-or

I made a reproducible code as below/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long int a = 0x0;

    a |= (1 << 31);

    printf("a: 0x%lx\n", a);

}
```

I expect 'a' should be 0x0000000080000000.

but the value is given as

a: 0xffffffff80000000.

Why are upper 32 bits filled with 1 programmatically, and if I want to make 'a' as single one and all zero value, what can I do?

Comment: The result of `1 << 31` is an **`int`**. Which will be signed-extended when converted to a bigger type. Try `1U << 31` instead, or `1L << 31`. Or better yet `1ULL << 31`.

Comment: Also note there there are still compilers and systems where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, even for 64-bit systems (*cough* MSVC on Windows *cough*).

Comment: Use `I32x` in the format specifier instead of `lx` ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Den-Jason it is somewhat clear the OP is **not** using Windows and its non-standard buggy libraries.

Answer (score 4):

`1` is a `signed int`. When you shift it 31 bits left you get a negative number of `INT_MIN` (assuming 32 bits integer and two's competent). Then when you assign it to the `long int` (assuming 64 bits) it is being signed extended to have the same negative value.

It is undefined behaviour by the C standard but most modern computers have arithmetic shift instructions and use two's complement coding.

You need to use an unsigned number instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    long int a = 0x0;

    a |= (1U << 31);

    printf("a: 0x%016lx\n", a);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G95GYffPM

or you need to cast it to `unsigned int` before binary or.

```
int main(void)
{
    long int a = 0x0;

    a |= (unsigned int)(1 << 31);

    printf("a: 0x%016lx\n", a);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bq3j4dWsc

Comment: The behavior of shifting a 32-bit `int` of value 1 left 31 bits is not defined by the C standard, even if the implementation is specified to use two’s complement, per C 2018 6.5.7 4.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
> type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

So the type of the expression `( a << 31 )` used in this statement

```
a |= (1 << 31);
```

is the signed integer type `int`.

Further (the same C Standard section)

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
> nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
> then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.**

Provided that an object of the type `int` contains  `32` bits and the most-significant bit is the sign bit then the value of the expression `(1 << 31 )` is not representable in an object of the type `int` and hence the expression invokes undefined behavior.

You need to use at least unsigned integer type `unsigned int` as for example

```
a |= (1u << 31);
```

or unsigned long int

```
a |= (1lu << 31);
```

Pay attention to that the result depends on the size of the type `long int`. It can be equal either to `4` as the size of the type `int` or `8` as the type `long long int`.

Instead of writing manually `0x` in the format string of the call of `printf`

```
printf("a: 0x%lx\n", a);
```

you could use flag `#` like

```
printf("a: %0#16lx\n", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
a |= (1 << 31);
```

to

```
a |= (1UL << 31);
```

`1` is an `int` constant, which is `signed int` by deafult.

Comment: it does not have to be UL, U is enough

Comment: @0___________ that's not maximally portable though.